# Delaying promises: .delay() doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

This is an extended question from [Throttling requests to 3rd part Apis with Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601683/throttling-requests-to-3rd-part-apis-with-node) . You can see my full code in that post if you want to see the sub functions and a little backstory of what im trying to do.

What i need to do is delay api request to an api. I am hitting the server max per second. I am trying to use Promise.delay but it doesnt seem to hold anything. This is how im using it.

```
function getAllRegions(req, res){
    getAllRegionsHrefs().then(function (hrefs){
        var chunks = _.chunk(hrefs, 25);
        return Promise.map(chunks, function(chunk) {
            return Promise.map(chunk, getRegion).then(function (getRegionResults){
                for(var item in getRegionResults) {
                    Promise.map(getRegionResults[item].constellations, getConstellationInfo).then(function (constellationInfo) {
                        var chunks = _.chunk(constellationInfo, 150);
                        return Promise.map(chunks, function (chunk) {
                            return Promise.map(chunk, getSystem).delay(20000);
                        })
                    }).delay(20000);
                }
            }).delay(200000);
        });
    });
}
```

Now this will make just about 9k api requests and it builds a universe based off regions, constellations and systems. Is there a better way of throttling the nested requests? At each nest, the number of calls exponentially goes up.

### Update

Still doesnt seem to want to wait. Did I mess up the nesting again? I added 1 more function in there that was needed for the flow. Also the chunking seemed to wrap a double array so I took it out.

```
function getAllRegions(req, res) {
    getAllRegionsHrefs().then(function (hrefs) {
        return Promise.mapSeries(hrefs, function (href) {
            getRegion(href).then(function (regions) {
               return Promise.mapSeries(regions.constellations, function (constellation) {
                    getConstellationInfo(constellation).then(function (constellationInfo) {
                        return Promise.map(constellationInfo, getSystem).delay(15000);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

### Error (per request):

```
 Unhandled rejection RequestError: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Comment: You cannot really use `for in` loops with promises like that.

Comment: `Promise.map` is parallel. It sounds like you are looking for `Promise.mapSeries`?

Comment: I actually seem to get all the data I need before I hit the limit. So it seems the loops do 'work'. Not saying they are proper though.

Comment: Sure, they do execute everything, but they don't wait for each other, and that's exactly your problem.

Comment: Rergarding the update, you need to `return` promises from all the functions, otherwise `mapSeries` cannot know what to wait for.

Comment: WOW that did the trick. thank you so much. I feel pretty stupid I didnt realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.map` starts all requests in parallel, so your code runs like:

- requests -> delay
- requests -> delay
- requests -> delay
- ....

But the desired behavior should be sequential:

- requests -> delay -> requests -> delay -> requests -> delay ...

each chunk of requests should wait for delay of previous chunk.

You could achieve this by chaining promises:

```
startRequests(chunks[0])
.then(function() {
  return startRequests(chunks[1])
}).then(function() {
  return startRequests(chunks[2])
}) // ...
```

or use [`mapSeries`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html)

```
function getAllRegions(req, res){
  getAllRegionsHrefs().then(function(hrefs) {
    return Promise.mapSeries(hrefs, function(href) {
      getRegion(href).then(function(region) {
        var chunks = _.chunk(region.constellations, 150);
        return Promise.mapSeries(chunks, function (chunk) {
          return Promise.map(chunk, getSystem).delay(10000);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

only innermost requests are chunked, others are started one by one.

edit: as Bergi said, returning result promise is required for `mapSeries` (and other promise utilities) to work. The first promise can also be returned for handling error or chaining more promises.

```
function getAllRegions(req, res){
  return getAllRegionsHrefs().then(function(hrefs) {

//...

getAllRegions().then(systems => {
  //next step
}).catch(err => {
  //handle errors
})
```

Comment: I updated my question with code that resembles yours and im still having problems. It seems to run much smoother with it but the delay still doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: more specifically. It seems I make 3,216 requests of getSystem before it starts to refuse my connection

Comment: Unhandled rejection RequestError: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT is the error im getting.

Comment: Thanks to you, and what @Bergi pointed out, I was able to finally get this working. Thank you so much!